# Does Git clone check out all branches from remote repository to local?

Tags: git

When I do a `git clone <HTTP URL to remote repository>`, assuming that my remote repository has three branches (master, develop, and features), will all the three branches get checked out to my local repository?

Also in local, can I directly use `git checkout <branch name>` to switch branches in the same folder or I should create separate folders for each remote branch?

Please clarify.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are used to using svn. git does things differently.
git brings all branches down at once. You just don't see them.

To see a branch you need to check it out:

```
$ git checkout develop
```

Now you will see the branch `develop` and it will be active.
At this point you can say:

```
$ git branch
```

And you should see both `develop` and `master` listed.
If you want to see all branches within the repo:

```
$ git branch --all
```

git takes a while to learn, but it is absolutely fantastic and well worth your time and effort.

Comment: git branch -r , returns all the remote branches and git branch returns the local repo branches. and one other command I found useful is git branch -vv which gives the mapping of local repo to remote repo..Thanks for your prompt response.